# Find the probability that the experiment stops after exactly 5 tries.

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

There are 4 black balls and 1 white ball in a box. The balls are taken out until the white ball occurs. Black balls return to the box. Find the probability that the experiment stops after exactly 5 tries.

I wonder if I am right in solving this task this way.
P(X=k)=(1-p)$^{k-1}$ $\cdot$ p

P(X=k)=0.8$^4$ $ \cdot $ 0.2=0.08192

Comment: Yes.  This is a textbook example of a geometric distribution.